# iPython won't autoindent

Tags: macos, ipython

I've never had this problem before and I don't understand why it's happening now so I'm hoping someone has encountered this.  If I'm using iPython in interactive mode and try to do a loop I don't get an auto indent (and can't add one in on my own).  So if I do

```
for i in range(5):
```

The next line is not indented, and if I try to indent it won't move the cursor over.  I'm using iPython 0.13.2 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

**EDIT**  I can space over to add indentation but I can't use tab and it's never added automatically.  I have also ensured that `%autoindent` has auto indent on

Comment: Do you get a warning about libedit when you start IPython?

Comment: @ThomasK I actually did get a warning and installing using `easy_install readline` was able to solve that problem.  If you write up the answer I'll give you the check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another symptom of the problems with `libedit`, the Mac equivalent of readline.

IPython will show a warning about libedit, which will instruct you to `easy_install readline`. Be sure to use easy_install, not pip - the latter won't install it correctly in this case.